# BlazeDS channel serialization options?

Tags: java, flex4, blazeds, amf

Does anyone know of an accurate and complete list of the serialization options for a BlazeDS AMF channel?  It seems like it should be an easy thing to find, but the official Adobe documentation on the subject:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html

...is not complete.

For example, it is missing the vital "include-read-only" setting as well as "prefer-vectors" setting (though that may have been deprecated.

It's making me think I could be missing something important.  Using BlazeDS 4.0.0.14931.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last LCDS developer guide is [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/adep_dataservices_jee/adep_dataservices_jee_p2_docs_developer.pdf) ("include-read-only" is included). There is no longer a separate BlazeDS developer guide.

"prefer-vectors" is not yet included in an official blazeds release - I suppose it will be added in the documentation when doing a release build.